# How do I install this command-line software?

Tags: unix, command-line, terminal

Here's a link to the software - it's command line and I have no idea how to install so I can use it in Terminal on my Mac.

http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/about/

Thank you.

Comment: How is the software distributed? Is it a package for Mac or is it source code only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple shell script.
http://git.zx2c4.com/password-store/tree/password-store.sh

You don't need to install it. Download it to your prefered location and make it executable by calling

```
chmod 755 /path/to/script
```

from a terminal window. Once it's executable you can simply start it from there using:

```
/path/to/script
```

Comment: I placed password-store.sh in my documents folder, navigated to there with cd and used chmod on the file which worked fine. But now I can't use it. I tried /password-store.sh, password-store.sh, pass, but I keep getting bash.

Comment: It's **./password-store.sh** to exectue it. If you just say /password-store.sh it means it is an absolute path and would be in the top-level directory which it isn't. If you call it as password-store.sh it has to be inside what's called the PATH of executables, you could move it to /usr/bin/ for example and call it that way from any directory without stating it's exact location. **./password-store.sh** gives the relative path meaning it is in the current directory. You could also use the correct, full absolute path instead.

Comment: You can check which directories belong to the PATH by **echo $PATH** and then move it to one of these directories, so that you can easily access it from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a shell script - put the file `password-store.sh` somewhere sensible, e.g. `/usr/local/bin`, make sure its executable (`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/password-store.sh`), and follow the instructions in the accompanying `README`.